# Multiple functions in java script work itself alone but not in one script

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, hide, show

I created different views as I want to show an html form in 5 steps.
The function for this is `showStep(x)`. Since I've added the functions `showCameraUpload()` and `showContactData()`, if I click on "Step2", "Step3" and so on, nothing happens... It worked perfectly before and if I put the functions I just wanted to implement in a new script they work well.

I get the following two errors:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
>   Uncaught ReferenceError: show_step is not defined

What did I do wrong?

Javascript:

```
    <script>            
        function show_step(x) {
            switch (x) {
                case 1:
                    document.getElementById('step_content_1').style.display = "block";
                    document.getElementById('step_content_2').style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById('step_content_3').style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById('step_content_4').style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById('step_content_5').style.display = "none";
                    $('#step_nav_pill_1').addClass('active');
                    $('#step_nav_pill_2').removeClass('active');
                    $('#step_nav_pill_3').removeClass('active');
                    $('#step_nav_pill_4').removeClass('active');
                    $('#step_nav_pill_5').removeClass('active');
                    break;
                case 2:
                    document.getElementById('step_content_1').style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById('step_content_2').style.display = "block";
                    document.getElementById('step_content_3').style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById('step_content_4').style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById('step_content_5').style.display = "none";
                    $('#step_nav_pill_1').removeClass('active');
                    $('#step_nav_pill_2').addClass('active');
                    $('#step_nav_pill_3').removeClass('active');
                    $('#step_nav_pill_4').removeClass('active');
                    $('#step_nav_pill_5').removeClass('active');
                    break;
                case 3:
                    document.getElementById('step_content_1').style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById('step_content_2').style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById('step_content_3').style.display = "block";
                    document.getElementById('step_content_4').style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById('step_content_5').style.display = "none";
                    $('#step_nav_pill_1').removeClass('active');
                    $('#step_nav_pill_2').removeClass('active');
                    $('#step_nav_pill_3').addClass('active');
                    $('#step_nav_pill_4').removeClass('active');
                    $('#step_nav_pill_5').removeClass('active');
                    break;
                case 4:
                    document.getElementById('step_content_1').style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById('step_content_2').style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById('step_content_3').style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById('step_content_4').style.display = "block";
                    document.getElementById('step_content_5').style.display = "none";
                    $('#step_nav_pill_1').removeClass('active');
                    $('#step_nav_pill_2').removeClass('active');
                    $('#step_nav_pill_3').removeClass('active');
                    $('#step_nav_pill_4').addClass('active');
                    $('#step_nav_pill_5').removeClass('active');
                    break;
                case 5:
                    document.getElementById('step_content_1').style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById('step_content_2').style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById('step_content_3').style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById('step_content_4').style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById('step_content_5').style.display = "block";
                    $('#step_nav_pill_1').removeClass('active');
                    $('#step_nav_pill_2').removeClass('active');
                    $('#step_nav_pill_3').removeClass('active');
                    $('#step_nav_pill_4').removeClass('active');
                    $('#step_nav_pill_5').addClass('active');
                    break;
            }
        }
        function showCameraUpload(){
            document.getElementById('step_content_2').style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById('camera_upload').style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById('contact_data').style.display = "none";
            $('#camera_li').addClass('active');
            $('#contact_li').removeClass('active');
        }

        function showContactData(){
            document.getElementById('step_content_2').style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById('contact_data').style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById('camera_upload').style.display = "none";#
            $('#contact_li').addClass('active');
            $('#camera_li').removeClass('active');
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Is that `echo'<script>` line really in `fadeOut()`? That would certainly account for the unexpected/illegal error; at that point, the rest of your JS is ignored, so the other function is never defined.

Comment: can remove about 75-85% of this by using classes or `id-starts-with` selectors. If you see the same selectors repeated more than a couple of times something can be consolidated

Comment: The `#` after the last `document.getElementById()` line appears to be the remaining problem.

Comment: Sorry for having bothered you with such a stupid question :( I am a total beginner... Anyways, could you give an example how to make the code shorter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a copy and paste error but it looks like you have a strange line with echo'

```
function fadeOut() {
    echo'<script>
        $("p").fadeOut(3000)
    }
```

Instead remove the echo:

```
function fadeOut() {
        //echo'<script> <!-- not sure what is going on here
        $("p").fadeOut(3000)
    }
```

Also take a look at

```
document.getElementById('camera_upload').style.display = "none";#
```

Should be

```
 document.getElementById('camera_upload').style.display = "none";
```

take a look at google chrome dev tools, the javascript console there can help you find future errors.

Comment: Sorry for having bothered you...was a stupid mistake but I just began with javascript...The problem is solved but somebody commented on my post that I could do this way shorter...could anyone give an example for this?